# Positioning of two HTML divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm currently having some trouble positioning HTML elements.

I have a div id called `game` and another one called `belowGame` and i need the `game` div always staying on top of the screen and the `belowGame` div always staying at the bottom.

Side note: Most of the width and height calculation is done in JavaScript since its a Node.js Socket.IO application.

**The current code looks like the following:**

```
<div id="gameDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div id="game">
        <canvas id="ctx" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="ctxUi" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
        <div id="ui" style="position:absolute; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 125px);"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="belowGame" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="chat-text">
            <div>Welcome to the chat!</div>
        </div>

        <form id="chat-form">
            <input type="text" id="chat-input">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot of current problem:**

[image]

Comment: Since the width and height calculation is done with JavaScript, maybe you could share the corresponding portion of code with us.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any CSS.

As always, there's several ways of achieving what you want. One of which is flexbox:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin:0; padding:0; }

#gameDiv {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

#game,
#belowGamge { flex: 1 0 auto; }

#game { border: 1px solid #000; }
#belowGame { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div id="gameDiv">
    <div id="game">
        <canvas id="ctx" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="ctxUi" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
        <div id="ui" style="position:absolute; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 125px);"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="belowGame" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="chat-text">
            <div>Welcome to the chat!</div>
        </div>

        <form id="chat-form">
            <input type="text" id="chat-input">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```